# How to add multiple colour in a round progressview after some specific interval in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using a custom progress view in Uiprogressview, and its being filled with a fixed color within 20 seconds, but I want such that it will be filled with the different color after 10 seconds, so that after 2 seconds it will look like a two colored circle,
here is my code:

```
#import "CEViewController.h"

@interface CEViewController ()
{

}


@end

@implementation CEViewController

@synthesize progressView;
@synthesize progressSlider;
@synthesize playPauseButton;
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.player = [[[CEPlayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.player.delegate = self;

    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackTintColor:tintColor];
    [[CERoundProgressView appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];

    self.progressView.trackColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.80 alpha:1.0];

    self.progressView.startAngle = (3.0*M_PI)/2.0;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setProgressView:nil];
    [self setProgressSlider:nil];
    [self setPlayPauseButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [progressView release];
    [progressSlider release];
    self.player = nil;
    [playPauseButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)progressSlider:(UISlider *)sender 
{
    self.player.position = sender.value;
    self.progressView.progress = sender.value;
}

- (IBAction)playPauseButton:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if(sender.selected) // Shows the Pause symbol
    {
        sender.selected = NO;
        [self.player pause];
    }
    else    // Shows the Play symbol
    {
        sender.selected = YES;
        [self.player play];
    }
}



// MARK: CEPlayerDelegate methods

- (void) player:(CEPlayer *)player didReachPosition:(float)position
{
    self.progressView.progress = position;
    self.progressSlider.value = position;
}

- (void) playerDidStop:(CEPlayer *)player
{
    self.playPauseButton.selected = NO;
    self.progressView.progress = 0.0;
    self.progressSlider.value = 0.0;    
}
@end
```

where should I make change to get my desired output, help please

Comment: I am facing the same problem. plz help

Comment: What do you mean, "it will be filled with the different color after 10 seconds, so that after 2 seconds it will look like a two colored circle" did you mean after 20 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replace `otherColor` with your 2nd half color. You may have to fix some syntax errors, my version of Xcode wont run on this computer so I couldn't check.

```
#import "CEViewController.h"

@interface CEViewController ()
{
UIColor *progressColor;
BOOL colorChanged;
}


@end

@implementation CEViewController

@synthesize progressView;
@synthesize progressSlider;
@synthesize playPauseButton;
@synthesize player;
@synthesize progressColor;
@synthesize colorChanged;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.player = [[[CEPlayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.player.delegate = self;

    self.progressColor= [UIColor orangeColor];
    [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackTintColor:self.progressColor];
    [[CERoundProgressView appearance] setTintColor:self.progressColor];

    self.progressView.trackColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.80 alpha:1.0];

    self.progressView.startAngle = (3.0*M_PI)/2.0;
    colorChanged = false;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setProgressView:nil];
    [self setProgressSlider:nil];
    [self setPlayPauseButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [progressView release];
    [progressSlider release];
    self.player = nil;
    [playPauseButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)progressSlider:(UISlider *)sender 
{
    self.player.position = sender.value;
    if(sender.value >= 0.5 && colorChanged == false) {
        self.progressColor= [UIColor otherColor];
        [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackTintColor:self.progressColor];
        [[CERoundProgressView appearance] setTintColor:self.progressColor];
        colorChanged = true;
    }
    self.progressView.progress = sender.value;
}

- (IBAction)playPauseButton:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if(sender.selected) // Shows the Pause symbol
    {
        sender.selected = NO;
        [self.player pause];
    }
    else    // Shows the Play symbol
    {
        sender.selected = YES;
        [self.player play];
    }
}



// MARK: CEPlayerDelegate methods

- (void) player:(CEPlayer *)player didReachPosition:(float)position
{
    self.progressView.progress = position;
    self.progressSlider.value = position;
}

- (void) playerDidStop:(CEPlayer *)player
{
    self.playPauseButton.selected = NO;
    self.progressView.progress = 0.0;
    self.progressSlider.value = 0.0;    
}
@end
```